# Wix - How to create a temporary file to use during an installation

Tags: file, wix, installshield, temporary-files, wix3.7

In InstallShield there was an easy way to use support files that were only needed for the installation.  These were all saved in the ISSetupFiles table, which is a custom table by InstallShield.  I'm trying to do a simliar thing in Wix.  I'm new to Wix and I haven't yet figured out how create files in the TempFolder for use during my installation and then how to delete them once the installation is complete.

Comment: In wix that seems to be hard: http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Temporary-files-in-WiX-td711418.html

Answer (score 0):

I use C# DTF custom actions and that has a very good story for extracting resources to the current directory of the custom action for the life of the custom action.  It's not that difficult to define a custom table similar to ISSetupFiles (but hopefully support directories and not just all the files in one directory ) and then  extract them with a custom action, set a property (SUPPORTDIR) to their location and then clean up at the end of the installation.

Comment: Can you offer anymore specific details?  Like I said, I'm a wix beginner.